# Info-apropos within current manual

Tags: documentation, info, apropos

`Info-apropos` "grovels indices *of all known Info files* on your system for STRING" and builds a menu of the possible matches.  However, with numerous manuals on my system, the process takes a while.

Is there a way to search *within the current Info file* for STRING and build a menu of the possible matches?

Many of my manuals are built from source and I'm confident there's no Org mode related matches in, say, the Python documentation.  Presently I use `C-s` (`isearch-forward`) to look through the current manual sequentially for matches.

Comment: Do you want to search the entire file, or just the index? The key `i` will prompt for index entries. `C-s` from the top node is the only way I know to search the entire file.

Comment: +1 for `i` - indices FTW!

Comment: Simple enough.  Looks like some of my "built from source" manuals aren't indexed.

Comment: @Tyler Yes, the goal is to quickly search the file.  Having a menu built would be nice.  I suppose I could do a grep type search.  What do you have in mind?

Comment: Whether or not an index exists depends on the author of the manual having created one. The quality of contributed info files varies quite widely, and it wouldn't surprise me if a lot don't have an index

Comment: Beyond that, C-s repeatedly from the top node is all I know. If I have some time I'll see if occur could do the job better